# Apply filter on svg clip-path

Tags: svg, svg-filters, clip-path

I want to apply a filter on a svg clip-path.

Here is my code,

```
<svg>
    <filter id="filter">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
        <rect width="200" height="100" x="0" y="0" filter="url(#filter)"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
        <image xlink:href="image.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </g> 
</svg>
```

Any idea?

Comment: What I tried is the code that I posted... I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: effectively, sorry for my english

Comment: I put a clipPath to an image so that the image move independently to the clipPath. Now I want to apply a filter to the clipPath..

Comment: And you've done that so you need to explain in detail what results you expected and in what way they are different from the results you're getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that you can apply a filter directly to a clip-path, but you can apply the blur on a wrapper g element like this:

```
<svg width="600px" height="300px">
    <filter id="filter">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"></feGaussianBlur>
    </filter>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
        <rect width="200" height="100" x="0" y="0" />
    </clipPath>
  <g filter="url(#filter)">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
        <image xlink:href="http://image.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </g> 
  </g>
</svg>
```